# How do I move the console cursor to (x, y) on unix?

Tags: c++, unix

I have used `<windows.h>` and `<conio.h>` on windows for this kind of thing, but on unix the only thing I can find is `<ncurses.h>`, which uses a lot of C and doesn't support a lot of C++ functions. How can I move the console cursor to (x, y), while also being able to do object-oriented programming?

**Edit:** I'm trying to make simple games in C++ using the console as a display. I know it's not ideal to do so, but this is for a project that can't use Visual C++ or any other graphics. Think something like snake or minesweeper. I need to be able to `cout` in different locations, without updating the entire screen in the process. It needs to be compatible with unix systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way is through [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
#include <iostream>

void moveCursor(std::ostream& os, int col, int row)
{
  os << "\033[" << col << ";" << row << "H";
}

int main()
{
  moveCursor(std::cout, 1,1);
  std::cout << "X (1,1)";
  moveCursor(std::cout, 13,8);
  std::cout << "X (13,8)" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The sequence `<ESC>[` *row* `,` *col* `H` (the escape character is ASCII 27 or octal `'\033'`) performs absolut cursor positioning.  On most common terminals this should place one "X" in the top-left corner, and the second in column 13, row 8 (counts are 1-based).

**Edit**: hvd’s comment is of course spot-on: This is very simple, but ncurses is complex for a reason. It is guaranteed to work more reliably and in a much wider variety of settings than a plain escape code.  Depending on what you actually want to achieve, I agree with hvd that you should be very careful before picking this simple hack as the solution to your problem.

Comment: So it's less readable than curses, less portable than curses, and equally non-object-oriented as curses. I wouldn't recommend the OP to go with this.

Comment: @hvd I agree. Maybe I should write that as well.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for me. I need it to work with stuff like cout, file i/o, and multiple classes and instances. Is there any other way?

Comment: @NickMundinger what exactly do you mean? You can call this function from anywhere and pass in other streams as well. It doesn't make sense to position a cursor in a file. What do "multiple classes and instances" have to do with the function? Maybe you should clarify your question as to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Or maybe you want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544280/c-wrappers-for-ncurses ?

Comment: @NickMundinger Thanks for the update to your question. But I'm not sure how your requirements stop you from using the function I provided.

Comment: @mindriot I think it'll work from what you described, I will try it out. Thanks a ton.